# Do geodesics move along level sets?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We define the graph of $f$

$
W_f = \{ (x,y) | x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in \mathbb{R},y=f(x) \}.
$

Given two elements of $W$: $(x_1,t)$ and $(x_2,t)$ and a geodesic curve $γ: [0,a] → W$ that connects them i.e. $γ(0)=(x_1,t)$ and $γ(a)=(x_2,t)$.

My questions are: Are all intermediate points of $γ(z)$  $0<z<a$, have the form  $(x,t)$ ? or Under what conditions, do geodesics move along level set?

Comment: You seem to be using the letter $t$ for at least two things.

Comment: No. That might even not be infinitely many points $(x, s)$ in $W_f$ so that $t=s$.

Comment: Of course in general that is NOT TRUE! Take for example the graph of the function $$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ \ (x,y)\mapsto f(x,y):=x^2+y^2.$$ The graph is the paraboloid and the level sets are circles which are not geodesics!

Answer (score 0):

Decoupled cylindrical level surfaces like

$$ (x,y,z) = (f(u),  g(u), h(v))  $$

Answer (score 0):

$n=2$ : Here $W_t:=\{ (x,t)\in W \} $ is a geodesic. That is note that $W_t$ is in a plane $P$ So if $c$ is a geodesic curve of unit speed in $W_t$, then $c''$ is in the plane $P$ Hence unit normal is in $P$. So we concluded that $W$ is ruled surface